# Add custom HTTP method in falcon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, falconframework

As many as HTTP frameworks support using the custom method and custom HTTP status code to be used inside the codes, I wonder that is it possible to do the same thing with Falcon?

I tried:

```
class MyResource:
    def on_obtain(self, req, resp):
        # do some thing
```

and I also add it to the `API` routes, but when I call this API I get `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` with this body:

```
{"title":"Bad request","description":"Invalid HTTP method"}
```

my question is that is it possible to define `obtain` on this resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use [Custom Routers](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/routing.html#custom-routers). Just an example:

```
class Resource:

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.body = req.method
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

    def on_example(self, req, resp):
        resp.body = req.method
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

class MyRouter(routing.DefaultRouter):
    # this is just demonstration that my solution works
    # I added request method into method_map
    def add_route(self, uri_template, method_map, resource):
        super().add_route(uri_template, method_map, resource)
        method_map['EXAMPLE'] = resource.on_example

    def find(self, uri, req=None):
        return super().find(uri, req)

api = falcon.API(router=MyRouter())  # just set your router
test = Resource()
api.add_route('/test', test)
```

Let's check:

```
curl -X EXAMPLE http://127.0.0.1:8000/test
EXAMPLE⏎
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/test
GET⏎
```

So, all what you need is just create `Router` and implement `add_route()` / `find()` methods. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, Danila.

Answer (score 0):

Falcon 3 has built-in support for [custom HTTP methods](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/routing.html#custom-http-methods).

You can either

- use the environment variable `FALCON_CUSTOM_HTTP_METHODS` which is a comma-delimited list of custom methods:

  ```
  export FALCON_CUSTOM_HTTP_METHODS=EXAMPLE,PURGE
  ```
- or add it programmatically to the `COMBINED_METHODS` constant:

  ```py
  import falcon.constants
  falcon.constants.COMBINED_METHODS += ['EXAMPLE', 'PURGE']
  ```